# Windows program to view all monitors and interact with them

Tags: video, multiple-monitors, remote-desktop

So I have looked all over for a solution for this and I am just about convinced that one doesn't exist. Basically this is the scenario:

In the company I work for one of my bosses asked me to set up 4 TV's that are each displaying a feed from Klipfolio for our sales team. On  3 of the TV's he wants the same feed and on the 4th he wants a different feed. I have a monster of a computer set up with 2 AMD FirePro W5100's and 5 monitors connected (4 HDTV's and 1 regular monitor for setting things up). Everything is now working, but I am running into a huge snag. I can't see the TV's from the location where the computer is. That means that I have no way to see where I'm putting the Chrome windows, no way to log in or interact with them, basically I'm screwed.

I have tried remoting in to the computer with my tablet with Chrome Remote Desktop (since that's the only one I know of that plays well with multiple monitors), but streaming 5 H264 videos over wifi onto a tablet is just not working. I have also tried parallels and splashtop with no luck.

So my question is, does anyone know of a solution? Some piece of software or a remote desktop solution that will allow me to grayscale and turn the quality down while still having multi monitor support.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This might be a problem solved more easily with hardware than software, if the graphics card can handle it.

The easiest way would be to get two more monitors (one for each video feed) that are the same resolution as the TV's and configure the TVs as clones of the appropriate monitors.

This allows you to see the outgoing video at all times, in realtime.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution finally thanks to one of my coworkers. [LogMeIn](http://logmein.com) is the perfect solution. It has multi monitor support and I can use it from anywhere.